# How to list collections in a db using ReactiveMongo

Tags: reactivemongo

How do you list collections in a database using ReactiveMongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how:

```
def listImportCollections = {
  val result = db.collectionNames

  result onComplete {
    case Success(r) =>
      println("result: " + r)
    case Failure(t) =>
      println("fail: " + t)
  }
}
```

API doc for this [here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10.5/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.DBMetaCommands).